# Why is jQuery relative values for .css() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/4UbKe/3/

Please check out the fiddle to see exactly why it doesn't work. I'm using jQuery 1.6

Here's what the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) says:

> As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to `.animate()`.

Doesn't work:

```
$('#block').css('top','+=100');
```

Works:

```
$('#block').css('top',function(){ return $(this).css('top').replace('px','')+100+'px'; });
```

Comment: I've run into the same issue.  You can simplify your JS slightly `$('#block').css('top', parseInt($('#block').css('top')) + 100); `

Comment: Thanks I would have voted yours as my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it appears to be a jQuery bug - looks like they had a similar bug before with width and other properties (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9237 - be sure to read the comments). Your JS fiddle example works fine if you use height/width but not for positioning it seems

Answer (score -4):

use like this:

```
$('#block').css('top','100px');
```

You can see working fiddle here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/4UbKe/11/
```

Comment: Your edit did not improve things. He's *not* trying to place the top at 100px.